# Creating a new tcp socket - server side

Tags: c, sockets, networking, tcp, server

I'm writing a simple server code.
After running the code,I'm trying to connect the server using "telnet localhost 8000" and I get the next error: "Connection closed by foreign host" and the server closes.
this is the code I wrote:

```
void main(int argv,void * argc)
{

//int socket(int af, int type, int protocol);

    int listen_sckt;
    int new_socket;
    int addrlen;
    struct sockaddr_in addr;
/*
#include <netinet/in.h>

struct sockaddr_in {
    short            sin_family;   // e.g. AF_INET
    unsigned short   sin_port;     // e.g. htons(3490)
    struct in_addr   sin_addr;     // see struct in_addr, below
    char             sin_zero[8];  // zero this if you want to
};

struct in_addr {
    unsigned long s_addr;  // load with inet_aton()
};

*/    

    listen_sckt = socket(AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM,0);
    if(listen_sckt == -1){
        perror("SOCKET ERR\n");
        return; 
    }   
    printf("Socket succesfulyl opened\n");
{   
/*
binding a docket
syntax:
int bind(int s, struct sockaddr *addr, int addrlen);
connect the socket to a logic port. 
so the other side will know where to "find" the other side
*/
}
    addr.sin_family = AF_INET;x`
    addr.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
    addr.sin_port = htons(8000);
    //binding command
    if(-1 == bind(listen_sckt,(struct sockaddr*)&addr,sizeof(addr))){
        perror("BINDING ERR\n");
    }
    printf("Binding succesfully done\n");

/* Listen()
Before any connections can be accepted, the socket must be told to listen 
for connections and also the maximum number of pending connections using listen()

Includes:

#include <sys/socket.h>

Syntax:
int listen(int socket, int backlog);
socket - the socket file descriptor
backlog - the max number of pedding the socket will hold

C source:
*/

    listen(listen_sckt,2);
/*
To actually tell the server to accept a connection, you have to use the function accept()

Includes:

#include <sys/socket.h>

Syntax:

int accept(int s, struct sockaddr *addr, int *addrlen);
*/
    addrlen = sizeof(struct sockaddr_in);
    new_socket = accept(listen_sckt,(struct sockaddr*)&addr,&addrlen);
    if(new_socket<0){
        perror("Accept ERR\n");
    }    
    printf("Acept success\n");   
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: It is because your server does nothing after accepting a connection and printing a message. Proceed on implementing your server. Also the type of return value should be `int`, which is defined in the standard.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because once you have accepted the connection, you exit the program which causes all descriptors (including sockets) to be closed.

If you want to do something with the socket, you should do that after the `accept` call. Like having a read/write loop.

And you should probably have a loop around the whole thing, so your program can accept new connections once the previous is closed.